# Is there a standard way of packaging a Javascript GUI control?

Tags: javascript

Is there a standard way (or ways) of packaging a Javascript GUI control such that it is easy for others to use and evaluate?

For example - should classes be named a certain way, should certain methods always be implemented?

Is a *raw* Javascript GUI control easy to use, or should it have a wrapper to make it usable in a framework?  Currently, the code is not written for any framework.

Some background: I am a long time C# (WinForms) developer.  To learn Javascript/HTML5, I ported one of my C# GUI projects, a spiral-shaped slider/track-bar, to Javascript and implemented a test harness using a HTML page.  My plan is to use JSDoc to generate documentation once the classes/methods are stable.

Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Comment: Its the wild west out in javascriptland. There is no standard for that unless you're using a framework such as vue.js

Answer (score 2):

There are a few best practices:

1. Use as few dependencies as possible.
   Dependencies increase the package size and add the possibility that someone up the chain will insert a vulnerability. One dependency may be including a dozen more.
2. Don't put things in the global scope.
   You can't trust other modules not to collide with you. If you must, pick a unique name.
3. Set `"use-strict"`.
   Use strict forces the browser to use more precise interpretation of your code. It can reduce errors and boost performance.
4. Don't `eval`.
   While not necessarily evil, it's dangerous and often is a shortcut to doing something right.

As with all best practices, there are cases to ignore each of these.

There are some common patterns that js elements use when attaching to a page. Most typical is for an element that most closely matches the behavior is added to the document with a class that the script recognizes. For example `<input type="number" class="praise-helix"></input>`. HTML5 also supports custom data attributes, meaning that this is valid `<input type="number" data-helix></input>`.

Comment: 5. Make an NPM package and *document* it with useful examples.